# Add image in Readme.md for VS-code extension

Tags: image, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, readme

I am Creating snippet extention of react-native for VS-code. In that I want to add some images into README.md file, which finally show images on marketplace inside description tab of my extention.

I have tried below things in README.md but it gives me error:

```
![feature X](/images/SnippetDemo1.png)
```

`ERROR  Couldn't detect the repository where this extension is published. The image '/images/SnippetDemo1.png' will be broken in README.md. GitHub/GitLab repositories will be automatically detected. Otherwise, please provide the repository URL in package.json or use the --baseContentUrl and --baseImagesUrl options.`

Comment: "please provide the repository URL in package.json or use the --baseContentUrl and --baseImagesUrl options" cannot be clearer.

Comment: So I have to upload my image on repo or full extension code?

Comment: Or where do I have to use  --baseContentUrl and --baseImagesUrl options?
Can you please give more detail, because I know I have to do that but am unable to figure out how to do it?

Comment: You can refer to `vsce` documentation, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-vsce

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a `repository` listed in your `package.json` as the error states:

```
{
  "name": "cotr-snippets",
  "displayName": "COTR Snippets",
  "publisher": "CodeontheRocks",
  "repository": "https://github.com/CodeOTR/cotr-snippets",
...
}
```

When the extension is published, the image address in the README will be updated to use the GitHub repo image.

**README.md**

```
![COTR Snippets](./cotr_snippets.png)
```

**VS Code Extension Image Address**

```
https://github.com/CodeOTR/cotr-snippets/raw/HEAD/cotr_snippets.png
```

Check out my [VS Code Extension repo](https://github.com/CodeOTR/cotr-snippets) for reference